Rsync total progress with interrupted transfer
I'm aware of being able to display the total progress of an rsync transfer using --info=progress2, and adding --no-i-r to not have it scan incrementally and display the total progress from the start.
rsync -a --info=progress2 --no-i-r <local directory> <remote host>:<remote directory>

When I interrupt a large transfer using these options and restart it, I can see that it continues where it left off/skips everything that has already been transferred, but the percentage and ETA do not seem to take into account that the transfer has already been partially completed and rsync just restarts the progress completely. This will also cause it to not finish at 100%, but at 100-X%, where X is the percentage that has already been transferred. And the ETA does not finish at 0:00:00 either. The very last remaining time it shows is the time it thinks it still needs to take to transfer everything that had already been transferred before.
Is there any way to have rsync show the actual total progress of an interrupted transfer? Or to just discard the progress of that which has already been transferred and only show the progress for the newly transferred files?
I'm using rsync v3.2.7

To some extent the transfer statistics can be only estimates. Consider the situation where you have 100 different large files to transfer. In scenario #1 only one block in each file has changed but I'm scenario #2 everything has changed and there are no similarities other than size. The initial estimates are likely to be the same but the second scenario will be impacted by the time taken to transfer all data across the network

The reminder of your question seems to describe a bug, and you would be best placed to submit this either to your OS/distribution or directly to the rsync team

@ChrisDavies I'm not sure what scenarios you're describing or how they relate to my question. I'm not changing anything in my local directory. I'm just stopping rsync, immediately running it again and observing that while it does pick up where it left off in terms of data the progress2 indicator is essentially useless because it doesn't take this into account and acts as if I'm transferring the entire directory again. I've always seen this behavior but I couldn't find anyone having asked about this before anywhere so I figured I'd try it here. I guess I could try the rsync mailing list as well

What @ChrisDavies meant to suggest is that you should report this as a bug to the rsync maintainers.

@Vilinkameni Yes I got that part, but as I'm personally not sure on whether this is a bug I'd rather first ask if it is or if it's intended behavior

I'd expect the initial estimate for a partially transferred directory tree to be wildly off, although the --no-inc-recursive flag should mitigate that somewhat as that tells rsync to check the entire tree before starting any processing. The part that I suspect is a bug is where you describe that the end state isn't 100% but is missing the percentage already copied

You should eliminate the --info=progress2 and just let rsync transfer.  You can manually track the progress easily.  Use this calculation.
